# Subsetting a RasterBrick based on values in a RasterLayer

Tags: r, raster, spatial

I have one RasterBrick with 172 layers (every layer corresponds to a different time step), that we can call `m`.

For every cell of m, I would like to keep only the values that are bigger than the mean across all layers (one mean value per cell). Then, I would like to calculate the mean of this new "filtered" RasterBrick.

I calculated a RasterLayer with the mean value of each cell of `m`:

```
mean_m <- mean(m, na.rm = TRUE)
```

And then did:

```
c <- m > mean_m
```

But what I get is a RasterBrick of boolean values (0 or 1). I then tried to do:

```
m[[c]]
```

It still didn't work.

Is there an easy way of doing this using the Raster format on R? I know that I could convert the Raster* files to dataframes, but I believe working with Raster* would speed up my workflow tremendously.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "terra" for that (the replacement of "raster")

Example data

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))
```

Solution

```
m <- mean(s)
x <- ifel(s > m, s, NA)
res <- mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
```

You can also do

```
res2 <- app(s, \(x) mean(x[x > mean(x)]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems to be what I was looking for! I still have some doubts.

Since I have multiple variables stored in my NetCDF file, with the raster package I did: 
`file_brick <- brick(myfilename, package="raster", varname = myvariablename)`.

I've been reading the documentation of the function `rast` from terra, but I haven't found a similar solution. The function reads instead all variables into layers of the SpatRaster object. 

Another thing that I noticed is that with terra the resolution is 1x1 instead of 0.083x0.083 (although nrow and ncol are consistent).

Comment: With raster it is `b <- brick(filename, varname = variablename)`. With terra it is, `r <- rast(filename, variablename)`.  There is no "package" argument in either case.